# Using Collections to enrich GetStream.io feed activity

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

I am developing a React Web App with GetStream at the core.

I have been reviewing [Collections](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#collections).  I was wondering if/how it can be used to enrich feed/activity data if I was to "upsert" user profile and product information.

Answer (score 0):

We are launching a new version of the JS client that performs enrichment out-of-the-box using Stream's collections as data storage.

This feature is currently in beta/stealth mode and yet to be documented but it is ready and fully functional. If you are willing to read some code and test it, you can try it out by installing the latest beta from npm (eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/getstream/v/3.21.0-beta.2).

UPDATE: enrichment functionality is now merged on trunk, all versions > 3.21.0 of the JS client have that included. Docs coming on the site soon!

Comment: Thanks - had been testing [Stream React Component](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-react-components) and had installed 3.21.0-beta2 to review "Reactions", I'll check out "Collections" after I sort out

`TypeError: jwt.sign is not a function
 at Object../node_modules/getstream/lib/lib/signing.js.exports.JWTUserSessionToken (signing.js:163)
 at StreamClient.createUserSessionToken (client.js:597)`

Comment: and to think i was > < this close to being rude and direct messaging you on twitter asking about this very thing. I'll join in the beta evaluation... I was hoping this was the direction Collections were designed for.

Comment: yeah can't wait for the docs or a sample... having to sift through git commits to find the api hurts